# Show that $H= \{x^2 : x \in G\}$ is a subgroup of $G$ for given condition.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, in which $(ab)^3 = a^3b^3$ for all $a, b \in G$. Show that $H= \{x^2 : x \in G\}$ is a subgroup of $G$

Now, in $(ab)^3 = a^3b^3$ after pre and post multiplying by $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ respecticely, gives $(ba)^2 = a^2b^2.$

Also, $e^2 = e$ , so identity has correct form to be in H and for $a^2$ and $b^2$ , closure under multiplication is also satisfied by above condition. But how to show closure under inverses? Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
(x^2)^{-1} = (x^{-1})^2.
$$

Comment: Can you give an example of  group $G$ where the condition $(ab)^3 = a^3b^3$ for all $a, b\in G$ holds but the group is not abelian?